# Anaconda 4.3.0 with python 3.6 (64 bit) installer setup crash windows

Tags: anaconda

I downloaded the setup from https://www.continuum.io/downloads, Anaconda 4.3.0 for windows, Python version 3.6 (64-bit). The download was successful but when I ran the installer, the setup wizard crashes. Windows pop up a dialog with the message saying, "**Anaconda3 Installer has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program**", while the wizard is at "**Extract: _system_path.py**" step.

I have tried downloading the installer multiple times using different browsers and download managers, thinking that it might be a download issue, but I got the same result every time. Could there a problem with the windows installer from the download page? Please suggest any solutions for getting this installation done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded again yesterday and it worked. Guess it was some issue with the installer downloaded last time I was trying